# Check annotation on a variable in kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

I have to check if a particular variable inside a kotlin data class has an annotation present or not.

Annotation class

```
annotation class Test(
    val identifier: String
)
```

Data class

```
data class Player(
    val name: String,
    @property:Test("stance")
    val stance: String,
    @property:Test("check")
    val check: String
)
```

I have to check if a particular variable inside this player object has the Test annotation present or not.

```
fun execute(player: Player) {

   //while this works, but i have to check for a specific variable
    player::class.members.forEach{
        val testAnnotation = it.findAnnotation<Test>()
        if(testAnnotation != null) {
            // DO something
        }
    }


I need to do something like
      player.check.hasAnnotation<Test>()

}
```

Would appreciate any help here, TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `::` operator to create a member reference

```
player::check.hasAnnotation<Test>()
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#property-references